# What does this symbol mean?

Tags: symbols

[image]
I think it is an ancient symbol maybe lemurian, Egyptian, etc

Comment: Just to clarify: Is this genuinely a symbol whose meaning you don't know and are hoping we can help figure out? Or is it a puzzle where you know the answer and are challenging us? If it's the former then (1) it seems like some context -- some of the rest of the thing the symbol is clearly part of -- would be helpful, and (2) the denizens of PSE are not necessarily the best to help figure out what it is, though I'm sure we'll do what we can...

Comment: It's genuinely a symbol I don't know.

Comment: That's the only part of the symbol the other markings are different symbols

Comment: How did you come across the symbol? Did you find it in a book? Knowing where you found it might help us out.

Comment: The proper question would be - _What could this symbol mean_ ?

Comment: Even if the other markings are different symbols, knowing the context may help figure out what this one is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a puzzle or about puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can think of it as a

> Plan(A type of view in Engg. drawing) of a modern western commode/ toilet with few details such as a P/S trap, water outlet, seat/basin etc.